# Most secure peer-to-peer exchange of public keys?

Tags: encryption

Just what the question asks: I would like to have two Android users exchange public keys for use in a mobile app while not connecting to a centralized hosted server or website.

Answer (score 1):

Public Keys are PUBLIC: they are meant to be shared. So, I think it wouldn't matter how you transfer those keys. What is more important is how strong those keys are encrypted, so they aren't easily hacked or bypassed.

You might also want to check on these two questions:

- [Strong encryption for base64 encoded public key in Android](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33686/strong-encryption-for-base64-encoded-public-key-in-android)
- [how to secure Android Market public key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5564/how-to-secure-android-market-public-key)

Comment: I fully understand that they are public; my goal is to find a secure means of exchanging (ie. sharing) public keys without using a third party.

Comment: @SeanDorman Some DEVs put their public keys on GitHub. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: Again the goal would be to avoid third party key exchange; I look at services like Lavabit which was forced to shut down due to the fact they had access to the keys and while I understand public keys are inherently made available through a CA (certified authority) it would be safer for people to be in total control of public and private keys.